# 'Basic' attribute type should not be Persistence Entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am referencing an Entity in another Entity class and getting this error. Below is sample code. I have these classes in the persistence.xml as well.

What is causing this issue? I am using Spring data JPA and Hibernate.

```
import javax.persistence.*;
@Entity
@Table(name = "users", schema = "university")
public class UsersEntity {
    private long id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id", nullable = false)
    private Address address;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

```
import javax.persistence.*;
@Entity
@Table(name = "address", schema = "university")
public class AddressEntity {
    private long id;
    private String street;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "street")
    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. You  are mixing field and property level annotations - use on or the other. 2.  You have an Entity `ServiceTypeEntity` but `UsersEntity` has a reference to an `Address`

Comment: @AlanHay It was a mistake in the post. I updated it with the correct class name. So, which annotation should I use to fix the issue?

Comment: Yes, Address is referenced from the UsersEntity. In the backend there are two DB tables. User and Address. User has a foreign key address_id which is the id in the Address table.

Answer (score 18):

So try the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users", schema = "university")
public class UsersEntity {
    private Long id;

    private AddressEntity address;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

   @OneToOne 
   @JoinColumn(name = "address_id", nullable = false)
   public AddressEntity getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(AddressEntity address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "address", schema = "university")
public class AddressEntity {
    private Long id;
    private String street;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    @Column(name = "street")
    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }
}
```

Basically what I did was replace the long for Long. and added the @OneToOne
I removed the @Basic since its optional. I believe with that it should just work

Comment: you tagged spring-boot but you mention you are using persistence.xml (which will not by read be spring boot) Im confused as to what you are using. are u using spring-boot?

Comment: Yes, I am using Spring boot. persistence.xml is being used for the creation of entity classes.

Answer (score 9):

You missed the type of relationship between entities. E.g. you can define one-directional @OneToOne as

```
//...
public class UsersEntity {
//..
  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "ugdArea", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "address_id", nullable = false)
  private Address address;
//...
}
```